# Why can I assign one Type to an apparently different Type?

Tags: c#

I'm working through a beginner Pluralsight course (C# Fundamentals) and I have come across this:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("textfile.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

My question is, why can this happen?

I was under the impression that `stream` should be assigned like this:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream();
```

So why and how is it valid that `File.Open("textfile.txt", FileMode.Open)` can be assigned to a `FileStream`?

---

After doing a bit of searching I found that the return type of `File.Open` is a `FileStream` ...
can anyone clarify that this is the reason this works? Just so that I know I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: I don't want to sound patronising, but you probably need to do a basic c# course.

Comment: This works because that is how it was coded...

Comment: @DavidG That's exactly what I am doing, Pluralsights C# Fundamentals, can you suggest something else that would be more suitable?

Comment: It is probably fine - whatever works for you... Just questions about very basic concepts like "why/how assignment of function result to variable works" are pretty much impossible to answer in short post. Nothing wrong with the question, it just does not fit into SO format.

Comment: I seriously disagree with the downvotes on this question.

Comment: @CalvinSmith - please post comment about your disagreement with votes on [META](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) instead (with some explanation). It is exactly for discussing this kind of issues.

Comment: Please, for the sake of your reputation, RTFM before asking a question like this. Or at least see if what you're posting even compiles (hint: `FileStream stream = new FileStream();` does not compile).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works because the return type of `File.Open` is a `FileStream`.

You can always assign the return type of a function to a variable to that type, because, well, its returning an object of that type!

The other assignment is perfectly valid because the `new` operator returns a new object of the type it is given (`FileStream` in your example). Its actually the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
File.Open("textfile.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

Returns a `FileStream`

See the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx) and method signature:

```
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this worked is because File.Open is a method. A method can have a return type.

```
string mystring = 1

int q = CreateInt(mystring);

private void CreateInt(string x)
{
  return Convert.ToInt32(x);
}
```

The Create Int takes a string, and return an int. So the above code will compile. Just as File.Open Takes a files, and opens it, and returns the file contents as a stream.

This is not a silly quesiton. It is really a bad job on the instructor for not clarifying return type and methods before showing assigning "type to different type".